# How to invoke a function from another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a non-working code. I think it needs just a little mods and it should be working. I couldn't figure it out.  Just started studying JS.

```
var add = function (a, b) {
    if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') {
        throw {
            name: 'TypeError',
            message: 'add needs numbers'
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}

var try_it = function (a, b) {
    try {
        add(a, b);
    } catch (e) {
        document.writeln(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
    }
}

document.writeln(try_it(2, 7));
```

It doesn't work. I get "undefined" error. However, if I invoke function add directly...

```
 var add = function (a, b) {
    if (typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number') {
        throw {
            name: 'TypeError',
            message: 'add needs numbers'
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}

var try_it = function (a, b) {
    try {
        add(a, b);
    } catch (e) {
        document.writeln(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
    }
}

document.writeln(add(2, 7));
```

... I get the desired result. There must be something wrong with function try_it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because your `try_it()` is not returning a value, while your `add()` is.

Try something like this:

```
var try_it = function (a, b) {
    var result;  // storage for the result of add()
    try {
        result = add(a, b); // store the value that was returned from add()
    } catch (e) {
        document.writeln(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
    }
    return result;   // return the result
}
```

This will return the result of the `add()`. You were getting `undefined` because that is a default return value when one is not specified.

**EDIT:** Changed it to store the result in a variable instead of returning immediately. This way you can still catch an error.